# How to extract an enumerable datatable from database when column names and count may vary?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

How do I extract data from a data table in a sql server database, knowing that the table could have different column names/column count depending on the request?

I would usually use a SqlDataAdapter and then do: `da.Fill(dt)` but this is not an option as I cannot enumerate through a dataTable in a razor view. I wish to reproduce that table in a view using Razor Pages.

Here is an example of what I might normally do, but it involves knowing exactly what the column names will be and how many there will be. What can I put in the `while` to return all of the table data in a type that is enumerable?:

```
SqlConnection connectionCalc = new SqlConnection("<connectionString>");

                    if (connectionCalc.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
                        connectionCalc.Open();

                    using (var command = connectionCalc.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = $@"SELECT * FROM {tableName}";

                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        column = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        int FATUidSingle = -999;

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            TableUid.Add(reader[SelectedCalculation + "TABLE_UID"].ToString());
                            FATUid.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["FAT_UID"]));
                            ScheduledDate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["SOME_DATE"]));
                            TableStatusUid.Add(reader[SelectedCalculation + "ST_UID"].ToString());
                            StartDate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["ANOTHER_DATE"]));
                            EndDate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(reader["OTHER_DATE"]));
                            Progress.Add(reader["PROGRESS"].ToString());
                        }
```

Comment: you could use SQL to first query the schema of the table, then generate SQL which could utilise field aliases.  You could also generate your SQL in SQL and execute dynamic SQL from the SQL command

Answer (score 1):

Run a command like this first to get the field names, then you will know which fields to expect.  You could use it to build SQL and set ordinals to point to the column you want

```
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                    where table_name = 'EmployeeDetail'
```

when you make your enumerable list, make a list of 'tuples' of string and object perhaps, where the string is the field name and the object is the value

Comment: Thank you, I'm still not sure how to use this to return a list of column names in `while (reader.Read())` though because `reader[{nameOfColumn}]` has to be specific. How do I return the result of that query in the `while (reader.Read())`?

Comment: I would run a separate command first to get the names of the fields - aren't they available in the reader though?  Have you checked the reader properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you only worry about exact names but you know column sequence and datatype then you could simply rely on index of column from select statement.
E.g

```
Select * from Orders
```

Order table might have 3 columns. Id, Name and Price where id is int, Name is string and Price is long.

So you can do:

```
var id = reader.GetInt32(0);
var name = reader.GetString(1);
var price = reader.GetInt64(2);
```